# Find the limit: $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3 - y^3}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

We seek a solution to the limit question: $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3 - y^3}{x^2+y^2}$$

I have an approach and think I have an answer but wanted to ask the community first. My approach is similar to the approach BabyDragon used at this link: [What is $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} (x^3+y^3)/(x^2-y^2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153134/what-is-lim-x-y-to0-0-x3y3-x2-y2)

Answer (score 5):

We have

$$0\le\left|\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le \frac{|x|x^2+|y|y^2}{x^2+y^2}\le|x|+|y|\to0$$
so the desired limit is $0$

Comment: The second inequality may not be obvious to someone starting out in the field but nice short answer.

Comment: If someone starting in the field doesn't know, or can work her/his way through, the triangle inequality then perhaps (s)he isn't ready for two-variables calculus, @user44197 ...

Answer (score 4):

What about using some polar coordinates?

$$x=r\cos t\;,\;\;y=r\sin t\implies\begin{cases} x^3-y^3=r^3(\cos t-\sin t)\left(1+\frac12\sin2t\right)\\{}\\(x,y)\to(0,0)\iff r\to 0\end{cases}$$

$$\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{r^3\left(\cos^3t-\sin^3t\right)}{r^2}=r(\cos t-\sin t)\left(1+\frac12\sin2t\right)\xrightarrow[r\to 0]{}0$$

Answer (score 2):

Seek paths to $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ by letting $y = f(x)$ where $f(0) = 0$. We can rewrite our function: $$\lim\limits_{(x,f(x))\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3 - f^3}{x^2+f^2}$$

Taking the limit using l'Hôpital's Rule we find:

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{3x^2 - 3f^2\cdot f'}{2x+2f\cdot f'}$$

Taking the limit using l'Hôpital's Rule again:

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{6x - \left(6f\cdot f'+ 3f^2f''\right)}{2\left(1+(f')^2 + f\cdot f''\right)}$$

We may now substitute the constraint that $f(0) = 0$ and see if the denominator is zero at any point by seeking roots to the differential equation therein. We see that it is given by $$0 = 1 + (f')^2$$ However, since $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, the denominator cannot be zero along any path (i.e. there is no function, $f\in \mathbb{R}$, $\frac{df}{dx} = \sqrt{-1}$). Therefore, the limit exists and since $f(0) = 0$, the limit must be zero: $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3 - y^3}{x^2+y^2} = 0 $$

I like this approach because of its generality. What do you think?

Comment: Cool generalization. But as you can see, only f' is needed so you may as well assume that $f$ is linear. Alternatively, you can replace $f$ by its Taylor series and see $x^2$ cancels. But this is a great use of L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: @user44197, why in the above can be assumed $\;f\;$ is linear? I think part of the beauty of the above answer is precisely that: no assumption done **but** $\;y\;$ being a differentiable function of $\;x\;$...which, btw, I can't say whether it is general enough.

Comment: Another nice aspect of this approach is that it indicates that the limit will not exist if $y\in \mathbb{c}$. Since using
$f(x)=\pm i x$ which is a solution to the characteristic equation and satisfies $f(0)=0$, results in an undefined limit along this complex path.

Comment: @HarveyRyanJohnson But what about the objection of DonAntonio that your answer assumes that the path we take is diffrentiable which is not general enough since we neglect some non-diffrentiable paths?

Answer (score 0):

Separate the direction $[a,b]'$ from the scale $t$ and then use l'Hopital, so write $x=ta$ and $y=tb$ which gives $t \frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+b^2} \to 0$ as $t\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Harvey Ryan Johnson's answer (give him credit also, please!)

In problems of this nature, assume $y = K x$ and see if the limit as $x\to0$ is independent of $K$. If so you have the answer. In your case,
$$
\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2} = x \frac{1-K^3}{1+K^2} \to 0
$$

Comment: How the existence of the limits along *straight lines through the origin* proves the existence of the limit?

Comment: Once you know the limit, then there are any number of ways of *proving* the limit. This may require obtaining bounds on the difference between the $f(x,y)$ and the limit. See for example Sami's answer. The first challenge is to answer the question, "Does the limit exisit, and if so what is it?".

Comment: There are some methods, like polar coordinates, that many times answer both questions: does the limit exist? , and if it does what's its value? Anyway, proving the existence of limits by means of lines passing through the origin is not enough **unless ** the first question has already been answered positively...which wasn't the case of the OP.