# Limits of two variables functions

Tags: limits

I'm computing limits of two variables functions I do not manage to resolve them all.

4)$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+2y^2} $

Here I use polar coordinates with $x=r\cos{\theta}$ and $y=r\sin{\theta}$ I finally get $\lim_{(r) \to (0)} \dfrac{rcos^3\theta - sin^3 \theta}{cos^2\theta +2sin^2 \theta} $ but I do not see how to continue.

6)$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{x^{1/3}y^2}{x^2+y^2+|x-y|} $

For 6 I began using polar coordinates but do not manage to determine it too, how would it be possible to compute them ?

Thank you

Comment: Too many questions. Leave only a couple, indicating what you have tried and what problems you have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the limit: $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3 - y^3}{x^2+y^2}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643857/find-the-limit-lim-limits-x-y-to-0-0-fracx3-y3x2y2)

Answer (score 1):

For 6), as
\begin{align*}
x^2 + y^2 + |x-y| \geq y^2,
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
\bigg|\frac{x^{1/3}y^2}{x^2 + y^2 + |x-y|} \bigg| \leq |x|^{1/3} \rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding 4)** you have $x^2+2y^2 \ge x^2 + y^2$, $\vert x^3 \vert \le \vert x \vert (x^2+y^2)$ and $\vert y^3 \vert \le \vert y \vert (x^2+y^2)$. Consequently: $$\vert \frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+2y^2} \vert \le \vert \frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2} \vert \le \frac{(\vert x \vert + \vert y \vert)(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2} \le \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert$$ and $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert =0$ so $$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+2y^2} = 0.$$

**5) is not well defined**. How do you define the function when $x+y=1$?

Comment: Yes thanks this one does not exist, do you have an idea for 6 ?